# Google Actions Follow up multiple actions_intent_OPTION

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I've been playing around with Google Actions lately. I want to create a flow were i make a transfer. It consists of 3 steps.

[image]

On the first step user selects the amount, then the From account and last the To account.

The first intent has the `transferMoney-followup` output context.
The second intent has the `transferMoney-followup` as input context and the `transferMoneyFromAccount-followup` as output context.
The third intent has the `transferMoneyFromAccount-followup` as input context.

When i get from the first intent to the second one and the user selects an option i have access to the first one and the parameters from there.

When i show now the list again this time for the 3rd intent after the selection it never reaches there and the code is never executed and the 2nd intent is executed again. My guess is i'm doing something wrong with the contexts but can't figure out what.

```
const app = require('actions-on-google').dialogflow();
app.intent('transferMoney' , (conv, params) => {
    conv.ask("Sure, let's transfer " + params.amount +"...");
    let items = {
        title: 'Select an account to send money FROM',
        items: {}
    };
    for (let i = 0; i < conv.data.userInfo.banks[0].accountsInformation.accounts.length; i++) {
        let account = conv.data.userInfo.banks[0].accountsInformation.accounts[i];
        items.items[account.id] = {
            title: account.alias,
            description: account.balance + "$"
        }
    }
    conv.ask(new List(items));
});

//Create a Dialogflow intent with the `actions_intent_OPTION` event
app.intent('transferMoney.FromAccount', (conv, params, option) => {
    let amount = conv.contexts.get("transfermoney-followup").parameters.amount;
    let fromAccountId = option;
    conv.ask("Let's send that " + amount + " from " + fromAccountId);
    conv.ask("Where should we send them to ?");
    let items = {
        title: 'Select an account to send money TO',
        items: {}
    };
    for (let i = 0; i < conv.data.userInfo.banks[0].accountsInformation.accounts.length; i++) {
        let account = conv.data.userInfo.banks[0].accountsInformation.accounts[i];
        items.items[account.id] = {
            title: account.alias,
            description: account.balance + "$"
        }
    }
    conv.ask(new List(items));
});

//Create a Dialogflow intent with the `actions_intent_OPTION` event
app.intent('transferMoney.FromAccount.ToAccount', (conv, params, option) => {
    let amount = 0;
    let fromAccountId = 1;
    let toAccountId = 2;
    conv.ask("Let's send that " + amount + " from " + fromAccountId + " to " + toAccountId)
});
```

Let me know if you need any more information.

EDIT:
1st intent
[image]
2nd intent
[image]
3rd intent
[image]

Comment: Can you update your question to include screen shots of the three intents including the Contexts and Events sections?

Comment: just did @Prisoner

Comment: Can you reduce the lifetime of ```transferMoney-followup``` context to 1 and try it again? 

My feeling is that since the ```transferMoney-followup``` has lifetime of 2, it will exist after your 2nd intent finishes executing and this will mistakenly trigger second intent again.

Comment: @AzaTulepbergenov - I suspect your'e correct, and your comment came in while I was typing my answer. Add it as an answer since you deserve credit for it.

Comment: @Prisoner - thanks, but your answer is very elaborative and I like it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the lifespan of your two contexts are 2. This means that they will exist for two more replies from the user. So your "transferMoney-followup" and "transferMoneyFromAccount-followup" contexts are both valid at the same time. When faced with this, Dialogflow ends up picking the first one that matches the criteria, and ends up going with the "transferMoney.FromAccount" Intent.

You have a few solutions.

The first is the easiest - reduce the lifespan to 1. This, however, has a couple of side-effects:

- If the user says something that is handled with a Fallback Intent or that otherwise doesn't match, the Context will run out of time.
- The parameters that were stored with the first Context are lost by the time you get to the third Intent.

A little more difficult, but probably better is to handle these in your fulfillment code. You'd need to do the following in the intent handler for "transferMoney.ForAccount":

- Copy all the values you need into the `transferMoneyFromAccount-followup` context (or any other context with a long enough lifespan) and make sure the lifespan is set for "long enough". You can even make this fairly long.
- Set the lifespan for `transferMoney-followup` to 0. This will clear it out so it won't be caught the next time the user says something.

Depending on your needs, it might be wise to do the same sort of thing for your other intent handlers as well.

Comment: i can see what you're saying and i would probably go with the 2nd approach. But i tried to set the lifespan to 1 from Dialogflow and ended up with `final_response` must be set error ( haven't really understand yet how to debug this error yet ). 
Tried reducing both lifespans to 1 but still no luck. One thing i noticed though is my logging of the context gets me this :
` name: 'projects/XXXXXX/agent/sessions/1527712396023/contexts/transfermoney-followup', lifespan: undefined, parameters: { amount: 3, 'amount.original': '3' } }`

Comment: You tried to set the lifespan to 1 from Dialogflow, or from the fulfillment webhook? That error usually means that it either didn't get back something from the webhook, or couldn't process it. That context log looks correct at a glance.

Comment: From Dialogflow. Strange thing is the lifespan was `undefined` when inspecting it. Will try to handle that from the fulfillment webhook and let you know later tonight.